# Mongodb aggregate, match group, count and store relevant data to grouped item

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I aggregate, group and count video items to create a list of most popular videos, using aggregate on MongoDB collection. I want to store relevant data to videos like author, date, title. The function I wrote works, but it creates an array of the same video data for every time video is in the collection. How to insert relevant data to video only once for the item?

```
videos = Recentvideos.aggregate([
  // Match the documents to every video downloaded in last 24 hours
  { "$match": {
    "date": { "$gte": time }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$encodedUrl",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    "docs": { "$push": {
      "author": "$author",
      "date": "$date",
      "extractor": "$extractor",
      "thumbnail": "$thumbnail",
      "title": "$title",
    }}
  }},
  // Sort from most downloaded to least
  { "$sort" : { 
    "count" : -1 
  }}
])
```

Recent video collection looks the following way :

```
Recentvideos.insert({
    extractor:extractor,
    title:title,
    author:author,
    encodedUrl:encodedUrl,
    thumbnail:thumbnail,
    date:date,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use $first instead of $push?

```
videos = Recentvideos.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "date": { "$gte": time }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$encodedUrl",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    "author": {$first: "$author"},
    "date": {$first: "$date"},
    "extractor": {$first: "$extractor"},
    "thumbnail": {$first: "$thumbnail"},
    "title": {$first: "$title"}
  }},
  { "$sort" : { 
    "count" : -1 
  }}
])
```

Seems simple, but all of those [accumulator operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) are meant to return a single result (like $sum).  $push creates an array.  Granted, this solution will return the data in a different format, but seems like you might be ok with that.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Didn't know about $first, thanks.